# SIGALRM to interrupt syscall

Tags: c, linux, signals

I need to interrupt a syscall (`recvfrom` in this case) after a timeout. For this I'm using `alarm()`, however the resulting SIGALRM kills my process instead of only interrupting the syscall.

I've tried calling `signal(SIGALRM, SIG_IGN)` to handle the SIGALRM, but this causes the syscall to not be interrupted at all! The only way I've got this to work is by creating a custom empty handler (`signal(SIGALRM, alrm_handler)`) - the handler does nothing, but it still results in the `recvfrom` being interrupted without the process being killed.

I understand that the default signal handler (SIG_DFL) will kill the process, but I expected SIG_IGN to ignore the signal but still interrupt the syscall. I `strace`d a test program with SIG_IGN and with a custom empty handler, and they both end up calling `rt_sigaction(SIGALRM...)` without SA_RESTART. As far as I know, if SA_RESTART *was* set then the syscall would be restarted automatically, but this is happening with SIG_IGN anyway!

Is there any cleaner way to interrupt a syscall with SIGALRM without needing a custom signal handler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you tell the operating system to ignore a signal you shouldn't be surprised if when it's signaled it does nothing and ignores it. POSIX only allows `recvfrom` to return EINTR if has been interrupted and it's only interrupted if a signal handler is called.  When `SIG_IGN` is set [POSIX requires](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/sigaction.html) that "delivery of the signal will have no effect on the process."

A better way to to do timeouts on socket operations is to set a timeout on the socket using `setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, ...)`. You'll get either an `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK` error if it times out.

You might also want to look at `select` which can potentially eliminate the need to use timeouts.